# SQLAlchemy metadata conflict between model imports and alembic schema upgrade in test

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a Flask application with a PostgreSQL database, Alembic migrations and SQLAlchemy.

Recently I started writing an integration test against the database. I import a model, say Item, that is mapped to table "item" and doing "from models import Item" triggers construction of the SQLAlchemy metadata for my tables.

In my test setup, I have

```
    def setUpClass(cls):
        try:
            os.remove('testdb.db:')
        except:
            pass

        #Run db migrations
        global db_manager

        db_manager = DatabaseManager()
        alembic_cfg = Config("./alembic.ini")
        alembic_cfg.attributes['db_manager'] = db_manager
        command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")
```

This results in

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'item' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

I have debugged this to the metadata object being the same one between the calls and thus accumulating the "item" table twice to its tables array.

I have another pretty much identical application where this setup works, so I know it should work in theory. In this other application, metadata objects in the import and in the upgrade phases *differ* so the tables array is empty when alembic runs the upgrade, and hence there is no error.

Sorry I can't provide actual code, work project. Might be able to construct a minimal toy example if I find the time.

If I understood where the metadata actually gets created inside SQLAlchemy, I might be able to track down why alembic gets a clean metadata instance in the working app, and not in the problem app.

In the working application, "extend_existing" is not set and I'd rather not invoke some hack to mask an underlying issue.